# Removing the secondary icon from android notification

Tags: android, notifications, icons

How can I remove the secondary smaller icon on the bottom right of a notification? Since it's required that we call the setSmallIcon method for the notification, we can’t just remove the call for this method.

Is there any way to remove the secondary icon while retaining it on the status bar? Do we have to call setStyle and set a custom style for the notification?

Comment: What is "the secondary smaller icon on the bottom right of the notification?" You may wish to upload a screenshot somewhere and link to it from your answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think he is talkin about this one: http://i.imgur.com/4qe3jSB.jpg
Any idea?

Comment: Have you managed to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of it like that (works for Android 5 and below):

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  

Bitmap notificationLargeIconBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.notification_icon_big);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_systray)
                 //.setLargeIcon(notificationLargeIconBitmap)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue))
                .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().setBackground(notificationLargeIconBitmap));
```